# System of equations with summation

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, systems-of-equations

I need to solve a system of n equations with respect to n unknowns $x$. Each equation is:

$\sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}\sum_{i}^n B_{ij}x_{i} + d_{i}x_i=c_i,$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$

Expanding the summations with $m=4$ and $n=3$ the system can be written as

$$\begin{cases}
\sum_{j=1}^4 A_{1j}B_{1j}x_1 + \sum_{j=1}^4 A_{1j}B_{2j}x_2+\sum_{j=1}^4 A_{1j}B_{3j}x_3 +d_1x_1 = c_1\\
\sum_{j=1}^4 A_{2j}B_{1j}x_1 + \sum_{j=1}^4 A_{2j}B_{2j}x_2+\sum_{j=1}^4 A_{2j}B_{3j}x_3 +d_2x_2 = c_2\\
\sum_{j=1}^4 A_{3j}B_{1j}x_1 + \sum_{j=1}^4 A_{3j}B_{2j}x_2+\sum_{j=1}^4 A_{3j}B_{3j}x_3 +d_3x_3 = c_3
\end{cases}
$$
I've found the solutions by substitution, solving the third equation with respect to $x_3$ and plugging the solution in the second equation, then solving the second with respect to $x_2$ and plugging these two solutions into the first.
Hence I got,
$$\begin{align}
x_1 =& K^{-1}\left(c1-\left(\sum_{j=1}^4 A_{1j}B_{2j}- \sum_{j=1}^4A_{1j}B_{3j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{3j}+d_3\right)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{2j}\right)Z^{-1}\\
\left( c_2 - \sum_{j=1}^4A_{2j}B_{3j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{3j}+d_3\right)^{-1}c_3\right) - \sum_{j=1}^4A_{1j}B_{3j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{3j}+d_3\right)^{-1}c_3\right),
\end{align}
$$
$$\begin{align}
x_2 =& Z^{-1}\left(c_2 - \sum_{j=1}^4A_{2j}B_{1j}x_1 - \sum_{j=1}^4A_{2j}B_{3j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{3j}+d_3\right)^{-1} \left(c_3 - \sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{1j}x_1\right)\right), 
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
x_3 =& \left(\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{3j}+d_3\right)^{-1} \left(c_3 - \sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{1j}x_1 - \sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{2j}x_2\right), 
\end{align}$$
where
$$Z=\sum_{j=1}^4A_{2j}B_{2j}-\sum_{j=1}^4A_{2j}B_{3j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{3j}+d_3\right)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{2j}$$

$$
\begin{align}
K=&\sum_{j=1}^4A_{1j}B_{1j} +d_1 - \left( \sum_{j=1}^4A_{1j}B_{2j}- \sum_{j=1}^4A_{1j}B_{3j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{3j}+d_3\right)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{2j}\right)Z^{-1}\\
&\left( \sum_{j=1}^4A_{2j}B_{1j}- \sum_{j=1}^4A_{2j}B_{3j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{3j}+d_3\right)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{1j}\right)\\
& - \sum_{j=1}^4A_{1j}B_{3j}\left(\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{3j}+d_3\right)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^4A_{3j}B_{1j}
\end{align}$$
Do you think this is the right procedure? Do you have any clue on how I can generalise the solutions for a generic n? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just expand the summations to get  the linear system. Write if for $n=3$ and $m=4$ and observe.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the question following your suggestion.

Comment: Use matrix calculation.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific? What do you mean by matrix calculation?